# JS animation writes over itself instead of replacing

Tags: javascript, html, animation, raphael

I have this code for a digital clock using Raphaël library which prints over itself instead of replacing itself each time, does anyone know how to edit the code so it replaces instead of writes over?

*JS file referenced within HTML file:*

```
window .onload= function (){
var paper = new Raphael( 0,0, 400, 400);
var backGround = paper.rect(0,0,400,400);
   backGround.attr({ fill: "none"});
function startTime() {
var today=new Date();
var h=today.getHours();
var m=today.getMinutes();
var s=today.getSeconds();
m = checkTime(m);
s = checkTime(s);
var dig = h+":"+m+":"+s;
var display = paper.text(200, 200, dig).attr({text:dig});
 }
  function checkTime(i) {
     if (i<10) {i = "0" + i};  // add zero in front of numbers < 10
       return i;
    }
 setInterval(function(){
 startTime();
 },1000);
 };
```

*HTML file:*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="digital.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="raphael-min.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>

</head>

</html>
```

Thank you

Comment: you didn't mention that you are using Raphaël library (it is for drawing images, are you sure you need the clock in an image and not as a normal text? it would be much easier to edit and style)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't really an animation, since you are drawing an image of the clock.

What `paper.text` is doing is drawing a new text every second on the canvas over the text that is already there.

using `display.attr('text', dig);` instead of you can edit the existing text.

This is the corrected code:

```
window .onload= function (){
var paper = new Raphael( 0,0, 400, 400);
var backGround = paper.rect(0,0,400,400);
var display = paper.text(200, 200, "00:00:00").attr({text:"00:00:00"});
   backGround.attr({ fill: "none"});
function startTime() {
var today=new Date();
var h=today.getHours();
var m=today.getMinutes();
var s=today.getSeconds();
m = checkTime(m);
s = checkTime(s);
var dig = h+":"+m+":"+s;
display.attr('text', dig);
}
function checkTime(i) {
     if (i<10) {i = "0" + i};  // add zero in front of numbers < 10
       return i;
}
setInterval(function(){
  startTime();
},1000);
};
```

Comment: The final outcome of the project is to combine the digital clock with another analogue clock face I have already created which is why I have to use Raphael, as once the digital clock is working it will be put into an image - thanks for suggesting paper.text.remove() it didnt help unfortunately

Comment: I think I got it! :D `display.attr('text','new text here');`

Comment: I am brand new to JS do I put that in just before function check time? what would I use for 'new text here' as the function isn't recursive?

Comment: *the digi time function isnt explicitly recursive

Comment: I edited my answer to include that part, check if it works :)

Comment: THANK YOU - you have saved us many hours of going around in circles :)